# Recursive search for sites using Client Object Model using Site Id (GUID)

Tags: caml, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-clientobject

Using the Client Object Model I am looking for the most efficient way to search a SharePoint server and determine if a specific subsite exists given its unique ID (GUID).  We are storing the GUID in our external system because we need to get back to the site and the GUID is the only property that can not change.  I know that CAML can be used to search for data within a specific site.  However, I haven't been able to find an API that will do this for subsites.  I am forced to do a recursive search and use a for loop.  In my case, we could have thousands of sites nested on our server.

This logic does one level -- but is not efficient when thousands of subsites exists.

```
    public bool SiteExists(ClientContext context, string myGuid)
    {
        Web oWebsite = context.Web;
        context.Load(oWebsite, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title, website => website.Description, website => website.Id);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        for (int i = 0; i != oWebsite.Webs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (String.Compare(oWebsite.Webs[i].Id.ToString(), myGuid, true) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool SiteExists(ClientContext context, string myGuid) {
    Guid id = new Guid(myGuid);
    Site site = context.Site;
    Web foundWeb = site.OpenWebById(id);

    context.Load(foundWeb);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    if(foundWeb != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```